# Python PIL CGM support

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

What would be the best way to read [CGM format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Graphics_Metafile) files using Python ? 
PIL does not seem to support it.

Comment: Have you heard of `CGMloader.py`? Might be worth looking into using that.

Comment: "Computer Graphics Metafile (CGM) is a free and open international standard file format for 2D vector graphics, raster graphics, and text, and is defined by ISO/IEC 8632." seems that it depends on what kind or data you have there.